# How to horizontally center a fixed positioned element

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a layer with an image inside:

```
<div id="foo"><img src="url" /></div>
```

and it is fixed positioned:

```
#foo {
    position: fixed;
}
```

but I also want the layer to be horizontally centered in the page. So I've tried:
http://jsfiddle.net/2BG9X/

```
#foo {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto
}
```

and 
http://jsfiddle.net/2BG9X/1/

```
#foo {
    position: fixed;
    left: auto;
}
```

but doesn't work. Any idea of how to achieve it?

Comment: Try using `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: `left: 50%; margin-left: -halfofyourdivsize;`.

Comment: @Zzyrk You can't apply `margin: auto;` to fixed elements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you position an element to `fixed`, it gets out of the document flow, where even `margin: auto;` won't work, if you want, nest an element inside that `fixed` positioned element and than use `margin: auto;` for that.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cJ49/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cJ49/1/) *(Added `height` to the `body` element so that you can scroll to test)*

**HTML**

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: tomato;
}

.center {
    width: 300px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
}
```

---

Some will suggest you to use `display: inline-block;` for the child element with the parent set to `text-align: center;`, well if that suffice your needs, than you can go for that too...

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background: tomato;
    text-align: center;
}

.center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
    background: blue;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/5cJ49/2/)

Just make sure you use `text-align: left;` for the child element, else it will inherit the `text-align` of the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

```
#foo {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lrsbck/DrRje/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `transform: translate(-50%, 0);`
Example Code: http://codepen.io/fcalderan/pen/uJkrE

CSS

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  border: 3px #555 solid;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Good option, but better @Mr.Alien one.

Comment: You're welcome, anyway they are two completely different solutions, both with pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

this way not cross browser you must set percent width for layer e.g `width:30%` and set `left:35%` and `right:35%` and `position:fixed`
this is better and work on all browser RTL and LTR