# Content will not center on page

Tags: html, css

Trying to spot why the following margin !important lines aren't centering the content in this fixedincenter div...Am I missing something obvious?  Posted any code that may be relevant, I'm wondering if the settings in the container div is interfering with the rest.

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: verdana, 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-image:url("cork.jpg");
    background-repeat:repeat;
    text-align:center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 68px;
    margin-top:200px;
    margin-left:425px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #777!important;
}

.navheader {
   top: 0px;
   height:34px;
   width:800px;
}

#fixedincenter {
    margin-left: auto!important;
    margin-right: auto!important;
    position:fixed;
}
```

And HTML

```
<div id="fixedincenter">  
  <div class="navheader">  
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800">
  <tr>
   <td><a href="/"><img name="JK Header" src="/pix/navbar/top.jpg" width="800" height="34" border="0" alt="Home Page"></a></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800">
  <tr>
   <td><img name="$MTArchiveTitle$" src="background/background-this_r1_c1.gif" width="800" height="200" border="0" alt="$MTArchiveTitle$"></td>
  </tr>
 </table> 
 <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="800">
  <tr>
   <td><img name="$MTArchiveTitle$_bottum" src="background/background-this_r2_c1.gif" width="800" border="0" alt="$MTArchiveTitle$"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please post link, fiddle, or html.

Comment: `margin-left:425px;` will override `margin: 0 auto;` also you are defining `top` and `bottom` margins as well, so remove them and move them up in the shorthand declration..

Comment: Also, looking at `#fixedincenter` seems like you are trying to center a fixed position element, than I would like to tell you that it won't work that way.. Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21310057/1542290

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Sachin's answer, another option is the following, which calculates the margin automatically rather than entering it manually. This way, even if you change your width and height, it will always be centered. Of course, make sure you use prefixes and this won't necessarily work in non-modern browsers.

```
.fixedCenter {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;

  transform: translate(-50%,-50%); <!-- using a transform instead of margin -->

  background: red;
}
```

Comment: It will work on IE9+ (IE9 with prefix, all IE+ without).

Comment: Yap, just notified, because some users still support older IE versions, I've upvoted anyways :)