# Fixed div get width from parent in 100%

Tags: html, css

I have tried to assign a 100% of the parent to a fixed div but is taking the 100% of the screen.

I prepared the code here
http://codepen.io/rodboc/pen/ZOOEWp

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 900px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
#wrapper .box {
  width: 100%;
}
#wrapper .header {
  width: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  background: #2ecc71;
}
#wrapper .content {
  width: inherit;
  background: #27ae60;
}
```

if a define the width for the parent in px works, but I can't do that, should be in 100%

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309975/how-to-horizontally-center-a-fixed-positioned-element

Comment: @MarcoValente Thanks but the question you mentioned is a fix width, in this case it is %

Comment: @rodboc, bro checkout my answer you might like it

Comment: It is inheriting the width of the container above it, which is 100%; it's your wrapper pushing the .box smaller. You've got your order of divs mixed up. Using a basic grid would sort all this out. Google Kindle grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually, move the header outside the box div.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%
}
#wrapper {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 900px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
#wrapper .box {
  background: lime;
}
#wrapper .header {
  width: inherit;
  position: fixed;
  background: #2ecc71;
}
#wrapper .content {
  background: #27ae60;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work properly because take the wrong width, and in some case add an aditional padding or margin to the right

Comment: First time I have managed to make it look as it should, now as you wrote me I see that problem. Probably I missed something. Will take a look again.

Comment: Try to add display: flex; to the wrapper. and tell me if it's okey now

Comment: But it's not necessary to use the flex, the width is not wront, it look a bit different because you have margin: 10px on the box, so if you add margin: 10px; to the header it will look exactly how you want

Comment: Deleted my answer and updated yours a little +1 ... and please use Stack snippets when possible, it make the answer more complete and independent of external resources

Comment: Ok will try to use snippet for the next time. Even though both of our answer were correct. Maybe mine just have very little editing.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%
}
#wrapper {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 900px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper .box {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 238px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: lime;
}
#wrapper .header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #2ecc71;
  max-width: inherit;
}
#wrapper .content {
  width: 100%;
  background: #27ae60;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="header">
      <p>Header</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Content here Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fixed position elements is not relative with its parent anymore.

Based on the documentation : 
[position:fixed MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

> Fixed Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a
>   specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it
>   when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on
>   every page. This value always create a new stacking context.

One way to fix this is to the max-width of parent and let the child inherit it.
So in your case it should be the same on the snippet i attached.

Comment: It's the order he's doing things in, not the fact fixed divs can't be contained. http://jsfiddle.net/C93mk/2141/

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your issue, change the styling of the header class like this:

```
#wrapper .header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #2ecc71;
  max-width:calc(100% / 3);
}
```

Check out if it could do for you:

http://output.jsbin.com/jaxasikose/

Comment: But my friend, in this case doesn't accept margins or paddings

Comment: It does accept margins and padding for the inner <p> element though and you can still text-align the content

Answer (score -1):

Okay here is how you fix it with a clean code:

```
#wrapper {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 900px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wrapper .box {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper .header {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #2ecc71;
}

#wrapper .content {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #27ae60;
}
```

Comment: I think that what the OP is trying to achieve is having the header fixed to the top of the page.

Comment: @MeilyChhon my answer also get downvoted but the output is correct

Comment: @rodboc, isn't it how u want it? LOL

Comment: position absolute and position fixed are not the same thing. Absolute will stick the header to the top of the page and scroll with the page, fixed will stay in the same screen position on scroll.